# Homebrew not installing the correct version of Python

Tags: python, homebrew

I was trying to install Python 3.7 using homebrew with "brew install python". When I check the version of python installed, I get python 2.7.10. Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to call python 3.7 commands with

```
python3
```

and install packages with

```
pip3
```

as well, also check your $PATH configuration, as is it usually takes the OSx python as default in Macs

Comment: Thanks! Using python3 and pip3 make it work as intended! Sorry, I am new to both Mac and python, so where do I check the $PATH configuration and will changing it make 3.7 the default version used?

Comment: @Doe your welcome, this is a good article to get you started with configuring your $PATH: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/